# Run a program from any directory in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have installed the astronomy software CASA in my computer, and I would like to be able to run it from any directory just by typing `casa` in the Ubuntu terminal. What should I change so that this is possible? I've tried the following:

```
sudo ln -s ./home/alcrespe/Desktop/casa-prerelease-4.7.0-22/bin/casa ./usr/bin/casa
```

... but it doesn't work. I'm no expert in Ubuntu, how can I fix this? As the previous line suggests, so far I can only access the program CASA in the following location:

```
./home/alcrespe/Desktop/casa-prerelease-4.7.0-22/bin/casa
```

Comment: please remove the `.` before each path and you should be fine.

Comment: It should have been: `sudo ln -s /home/alcrespe/Desktop/casa-prerelease-4.7.0-22/bin/casa  /usr/bin/casa`

Comment: On another note "why" install it in `Desktop` directory. It should have been in `/opt` or `/home/alcrespe` ...

Comment: Making a symlink from a system dir to a user dir is pointless. If you are the only user of the PC, put the program in your own bin directory at ~/bin and add it to the PATH (see [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/301745)); or if other people use the PC, move the program into /usr/bin.

Comment: @George I didn't install it there, it's a weird program, it comes as a tar.gz file and I simply unpacked it and put it in Desktop (just so I don't forget where it is). I just did what you suggested (removed the dot), and it says "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/casa': File exists"...

Comment: @wjandrea I don't have any idea how to add a program to the path, could you explain it a little more? I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'd only used Windows before. Thanks!

Comment: Please run `which casa` in the terminal and if it returns `/usr/bin/casa` then don't bother it's already at your disposal...Meaning you don't need that `symbolic link` any more

Comment: @WildFeather I edited the comment to clarify.

Comment: @George If I run `which casa` it simply doesn't do anything. How is this possible? If I try to run the program by typing `casa`, it says "no command casa found".

Comment: You will need to re-install that program. Run `ls /usr/bin | grep casa` and tell me what it gives you...

Comment: @wjandrea Since the program is not an executable icon, but a folder with a lot of scripts, should I move the entire folder to "bin"? I can't run it by typing `casa` even if I'm in the right directory, so I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: @George I've installed it two times already, it's driving me crazy. If I run what you said, it writes "casa" in red below the command, so it seems to be there, right?

Comment: @WildFeather Oh, it's not just one program... Maybe you'll want to try these (possibly outdated) installation instructions first: [Installing CASA on Ubuntu](https://casaguides.nrao.edu/index.php?title=Installing_CASA#Installing_CASA_on_Ubuntu)

Comment: @wjandrea Oh thank you, I hadn't found that before! Should I delete something before I try to install it following those instructions?

Comment: Yes its there alright... but i fear you might not be doing it right

Comment: Yes delete the `/usr/bin/casa` before trying that install option

Comment: That option is clean and instructive that will solve your problem but ping if you need help...

Comment: @George I followed those instructions and everything seemed to work... Until I typed `casa` to test it and it said again that it's not defined. I just want to burn my laptop, please help! I need it for a project and I can't even manage to get this simple task right... What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Did you add this `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/CASA/casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b` to your `~/.bashrc` file, and after did `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Your command should `casapy` not `casa` from that link. Try that!

Comment: @George I did that, but instead of `casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b` I typed `casa-prerelease-4.7.0-22.tar.gz` because that's the name of the file I downloaded. And when I typed `source ~/.bashrc`, nothing showed on the terminal... However, the directory is created and both the tar.gz file and the extracted one are there, I checked. And `casapy` doesn't work either... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57639/discussion-between-george-and-wild-feather).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues to address from my finds:

1. Doing it right:

   - You are obviously not following the `steps correctly` as I did and have successfully ran it using `casa` command, though the link says `casapy`.
   - Solution please follow the steps **verbatim**.

     - `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/CASA`
     - `sudo mv casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b.tar.gz /usr/local/bin/CASA`
     - `cd /usr/local/bin/CASA`
     - `sudo tar zxvf casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b.tar.gz`
     - Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file and then source it with `source ~/.bashrc`:

       - `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/CASA/casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b/bin`
     - Test it with: `casa`
     - Output:

       ```
        george@george-ubuntu-server:~$ casa

        =========================================
        The start-up time of CASA may vary
        depending on whether the shared libraries
        are cached or not.
        =========================================

       CASA Version 5.0.0-101
       Compiled on: Thu 2017/01/05 04:33:33 UTC
       Activating service name='org.gnome.GConf'
       Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.GConf'
       Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
       Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
       PYVER        -  2.7
       AIPS_DIR     -  /usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101
       SCRIPT_REPOS -  /usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-
       5.0.101/linux/lib/python2.7/regressions/
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/linux/lib/python2.7/regressions/': No such file or directory
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       ___________________________________________________________________
       For help use the following commands:
       tasklist               - Task list organized by category
       taskhelp               - One line summary of available tasks
       help taskname          - Full help for task
       toolhelp               - One line summary of available tools
       help par.parametername - Full help for parameter name
       ___________________________________________________________________
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       {'dirs': {'xml': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/xml',

       'pipeline': None, 'python': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/python2.7', 'data': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/data',
       'recipes': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/python2.7/recipes', 
       'rc': '/home/george/.casa', 'root': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101'}, 
       'files': {'logfile': '/home/george/casa-20170425-095553.log'},
       'source': {'url': 'https://svn.cv.nrao.edu/svn/casa/trunk', 'revision': '39214'}, 
       'state': {'unwritable': set([]), 'startup': True, 'init_version': 0}, 
       'helpers': {'info': None, 'viewer': 'casaviewer', 'crashPoster': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/bin/CrashReportPoster', 'dbus': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/casa/bin/dbus-daemon', 'logger': 'casalogger', 'ipcontroller': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/casa/bin/ipcontroller', 'ipengine': '/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/casa/bin/ipengine'}, 
       'build': {'version': '5.0.0-101', 'number': '39214', 'time': 'Thu 2017/01/05 04:33:33 UTC'}, 'flags': {'/usr/local/bin/CASA/casa-stable-5.0.101/lib/python2.7/casapy.py': ''}}
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Activating auto-logging. Current session state plus future input saved.
        Filename       : ipython-20170425-095554.log
        Mode           : backup
        Output logging : False
        Raw input log  : False
        Timestamping   : False
        State          : active
        *** Loading ATNF ASAP Package...
        *** ... ASAP (rev#3110) import complete ***

        CASA <2>:
       ```
2. Library issues. The latest version works on Ubuntu Xenial, and the version your installing might not work on your version of Ubuntu as I discovered when I tried to install your version `4.*` on it. So get back to your instructor for further help.

**Important Note:**

You might want to install it on a Virtual Device as I noticed your version insisted on creating a user with id `1001` irrespective of who owns that id. In my case the user `koko` was made the group owner of the `/usr/local/bin/CASA/*` directory. Permission given to folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11  12998   1001      4096 Jan  5 06:09 casa-stable-5.0.101/
```

Change the `casapy-30.0.9860-001-64b` to the one you download or the name seen there after extraction

Source:

https://casaguides.nrao.edu/index.php/Installing_CASA